# Using mqtt along with tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, mqtt, moquette

I wanted to use both http and mqtt features together so i tried using tomcat along with moquette as a shown below but ended up getting "java.net.BindException: Address already in use" . If there's some better way then let me know.

```
   public class Task extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Task() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            setup();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        doGet(request, response);
    }
      static class PublisherListener extends AbstractInterceptHandler {

            @Override
            public void onPublish(InterceptPublishMessage msg) {
                System.out.println("Received on topic: " + msg.getTopicName() + " content: " + new String(msg.getPayload().array()));
            }
        }

        public void setup() throws  IOException, InterruptedException {
            final IConfig classPathConfig = new ClasspathConfig();

            final Server mqttBroker = new Server();
            List<? extends InterceptHandler> userHandlers = Arrays.asList(new PublisherListener());
            mqttBroker.startServer(classPathConfig, userHandlers);

            System.out.println("Broker started press [CTRL+C] to stop");
            //Bind  a shutdown hook
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Stopping broker");
                    mqttBroker.stopServer();
                    System.out.println("Broker stopped");
                }
            });

            Thread.sleep(20000);
            System.out.println("Before self publish");
            PublishMessage message = new PublishMessage();
            message.setTopicName("/exit");
            message.setRetainFlag(true);
//          message.setQos(AbstractMessage.QOSType.MOST_ONE);
//          message.setQos(AbstractMessage.QOSType.LEAST_ONE);
            message.setQos(AbstractMessage.QOSType.EXACTLY_ONCE);
            message.setPayload(ByteBuffer.wrap("Hello World!!".getBytes()));
            mqttBroker.internalPublish(message);
            System.out.println("After self publish");
        }

}
```

config file looks like this

```
##############################################
#  Moquette configuration file. 
#
#  The synthax is equals to mosquitto.conf
# 
##############################################

port 1883

websocket_port 8080

host 0.0.0.0

#password_file config/password_file.conf

#false to accept only client connetions with credentials
#true to accept client connection without credentails, validating only the one that provides
allow_anonymous true
```

Server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
--><!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 --><Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"/>

      <Context docBase="AlmondGCM" path="/AlmondGCM" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:AlmondGCM"/><Context docBase="AmazeIOT" path="/AmazeIOT" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:AmazeIOT"/><Context docBase="MqttTest" path="/MqttTest" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MqttTest"/></Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: Can you please share your ```server.xml``` file ?

Comment: I know this an old post. but by any chance If you see this comment is it possible for you to share your code I am new to this concept and need some code for study. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Tomcat and Moquette are both configured to listen on port 8080.

Try disabling this in Moquette by removing `websocket_port` from your configuration.

Here is a related issue in Moquette that might help you: https://github.com/andsel/moquette/issues/150

Comment: it got fixed by using classPathConfig.setProperty("websocket_port", "8082"); Is it fine to use any random port?

Comment: Are you using WebSockets?  If not, then try disabling them by using the empty string for the port number.  `classPathConfig.setProperty("websocket_port", "");`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not using a fresh build of 0.9-SNAPSHOT, I suppose. If you are using the latest snap and it gives you a parsing error, please open an  Issue on github.
 Thanks 
 Andrea

Comment: Well.i can see only upto 0.8.1 on maven